# when i used the following code for logout time capturing in php the screen turns white and time is not saving in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
// check that the session exists first
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

// you should put your db connection in a config.php file and use mysqli or PDO - what you're using is depreciated
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("logtime") or die("cannot select DB");

// don't think I'd store password in a session...
// also, is username UNIQUE in your database?
// also, also, ALWAYS escape (sanitize) your database input to prevent agains SQL injection

$sql = "SELECT username, password 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."' 
AND 
    password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['password'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql: '.mysql_error()); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO exit1(username, outtime) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."', NOW())";
    mysql_query($sql_2) or die('sql2: '.mysql_error()); 

    session_destroy();
    header("location: index.php");
} else {
    echo 'There was an error. You have not been logged out.';
}
```

}

the problem here is when i click logout button the time is not saving in db and the screen turns white.
any ideas?

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: you are storing password open in database - very bad practice. better compare hashes instead...

Comment: Don't use **mysql_**, use **PDO** or **mysqli_**. Don't store raw passwords, use `password_hash()`

Comment: Could you please debug, if your `INSERT INTO...` code is reached?

Comment: here i am not storing password in this

Comment: when i used echo to check whether code is execting the code doesnt execute after mysql connection abd its not showing any errors

Comment: you compare password with `password = 'VALUE'` which means you are stroing them in plain

Comment: basically this application the password will known to all the people who are using this application bcoz we are only giving passwords for clients my main reasons is how to capture the logout time in mysql

Comment: first i have stated the session but also its showing white sreen and the logout time is not saving in mysql

Comment: Please any one give idea how to save the logout time in mysql db using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on your errors reporting. Also you are calling `session_destroy()` and `$_SESSION[]` before `session_start()`. Check examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` for that.

Don't store raw passwords in database. Use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions (`md5` is not for passwords hashing).

Comment: first i have started the session but also the logout time is not storing and its just showing white screen. here if password saves also no problem

Comment: @Muthukumaran Simple way how to check in witch line you get blank window: start from deepest code line and add `die('IS FINE');`, refresh -> continue till you see output of `IS FINE`.

Comment: can u please give me the correct code in php to save logout time in MySQL database.    it would be a great favor and help for me from u

Comment: @Muthukumaran Try `session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { //... rest of code`

Comment: thanks for your help finally i got the code to work and save my logout time in database

Answer (score 0):

this code is for session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "logtime");
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysqli_query($connection, "select username from users where username='$user_check'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

this code is to capture logout time in mysql

```
<?php
include('session.php');

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO exit1(id, username, outtime) VALUES ('', '$login_session', NOW())");

header('Location: index.php');
session_destroy();
?>
```